# Count number of unique values for all rows above

Tags: r, unique

My data frame looks something like this:

```
USER URL
1    homepage.com
1    homepage.com/welcome
1    homepage.com/overview
1    homepage.com/welcome
```

What I want is a vector with the following values:

```
UNIQUE
1
2
3
3
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `cumsum` and `duplicated`

```
df$unique <- cumsum(!duplicated(df$URL))
df$unique
#[1] 1 2 3 3
```

`duplicated` gives us logical vector of whether a value is duplicate or not, we negate it (`!`) and then use `cumsum` over it so we have cumulative sum of unique values.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` to add a new column:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(Dups=cumsum(!duplicated(URL)))
```

Comment: Maybe. I always leave the question and proceed to try to solve it. So I sometimes never know if a similar answer has been provided.

Comment: @akrun That's ok. I will take more care to look at other answers before posting. I actually deleted my post first when I saw the syntax was similar to the above. Later decided to undelete it.

Comment: I think it is okay to show the dplyr way of creating the column

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot.